# What to use for sync files from iOS/Android with xamarin to my own server?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, f#

I need a way to sync files (mainly photos) to my own server. Is for be used from iOS/Android devices and desktop clientes on OSX/Windows/Linux. The most obvious way is to use sftp and a lot of custom logic, but exist a better way?

Comment: Maybe you can Build your own private cloud.